# Laravel. No consigo redireccionar según el rol de usuario

Tags: php, laravel

llevo poco con laravel y no consigo aclararme del todo aún. Veréis, tengo una web con un login y según el rol del usuario introducido me lleve al home del usuario o al apartado del administrador. Pero solo consigo que redireccione al home, si quiero ir a la zona del admin tengo que poner la ruta. He mirado algunas soluciones por el foro, pero sigue sin redireccionarme bien.

Apartado del web.php:

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::resource('admin/users', 'AdminUsersController');

Route::get('/admin', 'AdministradorController@index');
```

Apartado del middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class EsAdmin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        //Con el middleware recojo los datos del usuario y conpruebo si es o no admin, si no lo es se redirecciona a la página del usuario, si lo es continua
        $user=Auth::user();
        if(!$user->esAdmin()){
            return redirect('/home');
        }
        return $next($request);
        

        
    }
}
```

Función del modelo usuario:

```
public function esAdmin(){//Con está funcion compruebo si el usuario es administrador o no
    if($this->role->nombre_rol=='Administrador'){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Controller:

```
class AdministradorController extends Controller
{
    //Creo un constructor en el controlaodor del administrador y le digo que use el middelware indicado
    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('EsAdmin');
    }
    //Si el middleware devuelve true, osea que avanza, muestra la página del administrador
    public function index(){
        return view('admin.index');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

haces un condicional en el Controlador

```
class AdministradorController extends Controller
{
    //Creo un constructor en el controlaodor del administrador y le digo que use el middelware indicado
    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('EsAdmin');
    }

      Sí es administrador {
      //Si el middleware devuelve true, osea que avanza, muestra la página del administrador
          public function index(){
              return view('admin.index');
          }
     }
     else
     {
          return view('otraweb.index');
     }
}
```